# Time Complexity of T(n)=2T(n/3 + 1)+n

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

so I started learning about recursions in my Algorithms class and am having trouble grasping the concept of what the "+1" impacts for the time complexity.
How do I go about unbinding the recursion given that it is treated as 2T((n/3)+1)+n?

Comment: You would better be served asking this question on https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ SO is for programming questions and there is no programming in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by repeatedly substituting a *more general* version of `T(n)` into itself, and spotting a pattern:

[image]

[image]

... after `m` substitutions. As you can see, the introduction of an addition term `c` does make the result somewhat more complex.

What is the value of `m` where this terminates? Let's assume the stopping condition to be `n = d`, i.e. `T(d) = constant`:

[image]

---

This is already getting a little unwieldy, so let's substitute in the corresponding numbers before we proceed: `a = 2, b = 3, c = 1`

[image]

The fractional exponentials tend to zero, leaving only the `n` and `2^m` terms. Which of these dominate?

[image]

---

Let's compare the above result to the case where there is no "+1", i.e. `c = 0`:

[image]

---

> Thus we conclude that the additive factor does **not** affect the overall time complexity.

(Note that the additive factor does however put a constraint on the stopping condition of the function, as it affects convergence at deep recursion levels.)